# Search results Highlighting using Lucene.net

Tags: lucene.net

I'm working on an asp.net application which uses Lucene.net
I need to highlight the search results returned from Lucene.
I believe there is a Highlighter class which serves this purpose.I am using Lucene.Net version 2.0.0.4 but am not able to find any Highlighter class in it.
Kindly help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While Googling, I found this link: http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.0/Highlighter.Net/Lucene.Net.Highlight.html. It might be what you're looking for?

Comment: I would almost expect that since it's been almost 3 years since this answer was posted. Looks like you can download the code from here: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/lucene.net/?pathrev=1069572

edit: documentation can be found in the above link's document folder, which is here: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/lucene.net/trunk/C%23/src/Docs/?pathrev=1069572